# Convergence Series

Tags: real-analysis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to prove $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|\alpha_{k}|\lt \infty$, given that $\sum \limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\alpha_{k}\phi_{k}$ converges …?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79204/how-to-prove-sum-limits-k-1-infty-alpha-k-lt-infty-given-that-su)

Below is a question that I came across while studying real analysis. 
Given that $\{a_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of complex numbers where $\sum_k{a_k}{b_k}$ converges for every complex sequence $\{b_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ such that $\lim_kb_k=0$. Prove that $\sum_k|{a_k}|<\infty$. As a matter of fact as I am very new to this field. I need some help. Thanks.

Comment: And interestingly enough, my answer to that question is the same as Gerry's below.

Comment: @mixedmath, great minds think alike. I should have looked for a duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\sum|a_k|$ diverges. Choose $M_1\lt M_2\lt\dots$ such that $\sum_{M_i\le k\lt M_{i+1}}|a_k|\ge1$. Choose $b_k$ such that $a_kb_k\ge0$ and $b_k=1/i$ for $M_i\le k\lt M_{i+1}$. Then $b_k\to0$ but $\sum_{M_i\le k\lt M_{i+1}}a_kb_k\ge1/i$, so $\sum a_kb_k$ diverges.