# $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists real sequence $b_n$ such that $b_n\rightarrow +\infty$ and $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that $\sum a_n$ converges, $a_n \in \mathbb{R}$, then there exists real sequence $b_n$  such that $b_n\rightarrow +\infty$ and $\sum a_n b_n$ converges.

Same to be easy at first thought, can we find such $b_n$ represented by $a_n$?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "can we find $b_n$ such represented by $a_n$?" Are you asking if we can use the $a_n$'s to construct $b_n$'s? Also, what approaches have you tried so far?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92778/convergence-of-a-product-series-with-one-divergent-factor).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Credit: Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis", Chapter 3, Exercise 12.

Let $$r_n=\sum^\infty_{m=n}a_n.$$
Then $\sum\frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n}}$ is convergent.

Comment: How do you deal with $r_n = 0$ for some (say infinitely many) $n$?

Comment: Apparently, the exercise is only for $a_n>0$. One can partition a general series to get a positive/negative series if needed, similar to @nayrb 's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intended to furnish an intuition to @Quang Hoang's answer.

**1.** First consider an integral analogue of the question.

> If $f > 0$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty$, then can we find a function $g \geq 0$ such that $g(x) \to \infty$ and $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \, \mathrm{d}x < \infty$?

A useful trick in this direction is to play with antiderivatives of $f$. For example, let $F(x) = \int_{x}^{\infty} f(t) \, \mathrm{d}t$. Since the integral converges, $F$ is well-defined as a real-valued function and satisfies $F' = -f$. Then

$$ \sqrt{F(0)} = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( -\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\sqrt{F(t)} \right) \, \mathrm{d}t = \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{f(t)}{2\sqrt{F(t)}} \, \mathrm{d}t. $$

So by letting $g(x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{F(x)}}$, it follows that $g(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty
$ yet the integral of $fg$ over $[0, \infty)$ converges.

**2.** Now the construction in @Quang Hoang's answer is precisely the series analogue of the above heuristics. Indeed, suppose $a_n > 0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n < \infty$. Let

$$ r_n = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} a_k $$

and note that

$$ \sqrt{r_n} - \sqrt{r_{n+1}} = \frac{a_n}{\sqrt{r_n} + \sqrt{r_{n+1}}} \geq \frac{a_n}{2\sqrt{r_n}}. $$

(This is the series analogue of $\sqrt{F(x)} - \sqrt{F(x+h)} = \int_{x}^{x+h} \frac{f(t)}{2\sqrt{F(t)}} \, \mathrm{d}t$.) This allows to choose a $(b_n)$ that satisfies the desired properties.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Because $\sum a_n$ converges to $A$, we can partition it into sets

$$\{a_1, \dots, a_{N_1}\}, \{a_{N_1+1}, \dots, a_{N_2}\}, \dots$$

where 
$$\sum_{i={N_k+1}}^{N_{k+1}} a_i \approx \frac{A}{4^k}.$$

Then if you pick $b_n$ as the sequence $B_k$ but with a lot of repetition, you can make $\sum a_n b_n \approx \sum \frac{A}{4^k} B_k$.

What remains to be done is choosing the numbers $N_k$ precisely and making the approximate equality more precise by changing it to an inequality and/or modifying $A/4^k$. There might be a snag with alternating sums, that is sums that have negative terms, but I think the essence of the idea is here.